# Model relationship many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have an Excel file which contains ProcessSheet,InputsSheet ,the process sheet and the input sheet are defined in columns like this

```
idProcess | Name | InputsIds | InputsNames

idInput | InputName | Comments
```

how can i model this schema in Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third table to join them together. This new table will have foreign key relationship to both the Process and the Input tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Input
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100),
    Comments varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Process
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100),
    Comments varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ProcessInput
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    ProcessID int NOT NULL,
    InputID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ProcessID) REFERENCES Process(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (InputID) REFERENCES Input(ID)
);
```